# Centralize a div with display-inline and affected by float

Tags: css

I've this problem, i want to centralize a div inside a header, the problem is: I've 2 another div(one using float left and another using float right), see below:

```
<header>
  <div class="left">Hello World App Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</header>
```

I try to use this css:

```
header{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:black;
  margin-top:50px;
  text-align:center;
}

.left{
  float: left;
}

.center{
  display: inline-block;
}

.right{
  float: right;
}
```

But this didn't centralize my center div(almost, but didn't because it was affect by the another 2 div's), what options here i've to centralize this div?

See my [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/wE6YthRmhLTm7Znrc4OW?p=preview)

Comment: The center div is centered on my screen (Firefox 28).

Comment: it's not, its almost centered, but it's not.

Comment: You want to center the element with respect to what? If you want to resize it with respect to the viewport, there is no pure CSS solution simply because you can't determine the size of the left and right floats. Also, you have to tell us what behavior you expect when the text in each element gets too long that they have to overflow. Otherwise the question is too open ended - we can't guess what you expect.

Comment: do you want the center of the text to be centered or the left side of the text to be centered? ;)

Comment: Terry - i want to center it with respect to the header, and its an image, but in this example i put a text.

Answer (score 0):

Try floating all divs left and setting width:33% to each.

Answer (score 0):

To work off of a previous answer as a possible solution, you could indeed set each to 33%, but to prevent it from scaling, wrap the whole thing in a div. EG:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<header>
  <div class="left">Hello World App Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</header>
</div>
```

css:

```
header{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:black;
  margin-top:50px;
  text-align:center;
}

.left{
  float left;
  width:33%;
}

.center{
  float:left;
  width:34%;
}

.right{
  float:left;
  width:33%;
}

#wrapper{
  width:1000px;
}
```